# Nav bar 'overflow' can't remove

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am sorry for all of the confusion and wrong post type. I will keep playing with it or try to get all the css in order so I can paste it correctly on here.

Thanks for the info and help that you were able to give.

Grady

I am not sure if anyone can help me but for some reason I can not figure out why my nav bar has a 'shadow' without any shadow tag. It is very annoying and I can not figure it out. I am able to change the entire navbar to the same color as the background but then it does not stand out. If you can offer me any advice or things to try that would be great!

Here is a picture of the nav during regular view and then I zoomed in and took another shot.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11217802/nav%20bar%20issue.png

I have tried border: none and box-shadow: none but nothing seems to remove that little overflow.

UPDATE:

I should have posted this to start with. I do not have the complete html/css as I'm using wordpress so the code is not exactly mine to share. You are welcome to view our site here, http://jrummy16.com/test/

I have just been using the console in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox to style it to that point.

Thanks in advance

Grady

Comment: Can you post some relevant html/css?

Comment: It looks like something in the div behind it. Use your DOM inspector to see what's producing it. I find Firefox's 3d mode especially useful for problems like these.

Comment: Nothing anyone can say until you post some code.

Comment: Link it posted to the site. Hope this helps.

Comment: @aDroidman Please see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Thanks George, I had no idea about that. New to this whole site.

Comment: @aDroidman Do you have the CSS property `overflow: hidden;`. Note for this to work as expected, the navbar in question needs to have a defined `width` and `height` properties as well. This tells the browser to prevent content overflow, when these parameters are met.

Comment: @aDroidman Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ3We/) that describes what I talked about above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with overflow or box-shadow. What you are seeing at the edge is just the continuation of the background of the parent element.

You can fix this by correcting the positioning of your blue support nav so that it properly aligns to the far edge and doesn't leave the small section showing at the end.

---

**EDIT:**
Looking at the actual code, there are two "rogue" pixels that account for your excess right spacing. The first pixel is from the border from css line 394:

```
#mainmenu.scaled li.menu-item a {
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}
```

You can either leave this here so the 1px border around elements stays constant, or you can remove it from your last nav using the `:last-child` pseudo-selector to set `border-right:none;`

So second rogue pixel comes from a clearing div that you have in the navigation. Deleting this div and applying a CSS clearing fix seems like the best solution. A basic clearing would be setting `overflow:hidden;` on the container element, but there are more robust css clearing you can use if your situation calls for it.

Comment: I added a link to our test site. Can you give me an example or tutorial to do that? Nav bars are new to me.

Comment: @aDroidman After examining your site in chrome dev tools, I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Sorry I went about asking this the wrong way but thank you very much for taking the time to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's your padding on your grey box. Set `padding:0px;` on that get box element and see if that does it.

Comment: I tried the padding and it did not seem to fix it but I may have been adding it to the wrong class/id.